# Don't validate if input field is empty (PHP)

Tags: php, forms, validation, field

I have a form which has a field that needs validation. However, I want to skip the validation if the field is left empty. At the moment, if the first user leave the field empty, the second user who leave it empty will get an error. I have tried with some logical operations without any luck. Can I get a helping hand at this please?

EDIT: Here is a working function:

```
function is_already_submitted($formName, $fieldName, $fieldValue) {
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/CFDBFormIterator.php');
$exp = new CFDBFormIterator();
$atts = array();
$atts['show'] = $fieldName;
$atts['filter'] = "$fieldName=$fieldValue";
$atts['unbuffered'] = 'true';
$exp->export($formName, $atts);
$found = false;
while ($row = $exp->nextRow()) {
    $found = true;
}
return $found;
}

function validate_registrationcode($result, $tag) {
$formName = 'Registration Form';
$fieldName = 'registrationcode';
$errorMessage = 'This code has already been used';
$name = $tag['name'];
if ($name == $fieldName) {
    if (!empty($_POST[$name]) && is_already_submitted($formName, $fieldName, $_POST[$name])) {
        $result->invalidate($tag, $errorMessage);
    }
}
return $result;
}
```

Comment: What is the variable you wish to validate as empty or set?

Comment: basic: `if(empty($var1) && empty($var2)){...}` or `||` instead of `&&`; take your pick.

Comment: nothing in what you posted contains `empty()`.

Comment: @LoveenDyall `$_POST[$name]` is the variable I want to validate.

I managed to get it to work now. This is what I wrote:
`if (!empty($_POST[$name]) && is_already_submitted($formName, $fieldName, $_POST[$name]))`
@Fred-ii-